# UIButton,UIAlertView setting action

Tags: ios, uibutton, uialertview

I have a simple question, please help me as I really stuck. What I need is to switch to another ViewController after login button is pressed if login and password are not empty

I have a simple login interface with username, password and login button. UIAlertView is shown when password or login is empty, here's code:

.m file

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    if (userName.text.length == 0 || password.text.length == 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete All Fields" message:@"You must complete all fields to login!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Good" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show]; 
    }
}
```

How to add action for the button to switch to other UIController? This one is crushing all the time `[self presentModalViewController: anotherUIViewController animated YES];` Here's also notification -"Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target ."

Comment: It crashes because Application tried to present a **nil** modal view controller. What is `anotherUIViewController` and how you show it?

Comment: anotherUIViewController is uiviewcontroller that I want to be opened after the login button is pressed.

Comment: So what I need is to switch to another ViewController after login button is pressed if login and password are not empty.

Comment: Your question is extremely broad, as phrased.  Do you need help associating a button press with a method?  (If so, I'd suggest you spend some more time with the tutorial of your choice)  Is your problem actually getting hte function to not crash?  The crash is -- as the error tells you -- because you're trying to push a modal view control value of 'nil' -- which is to say, wherever you're pushing the new view controller, you aren't giving it a valid VC.  Without letting us see the code behind that, we can't even begin to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only keep one of the lines as explained below depending on if you are using xibs or storyboards.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    if (userName.text.length == 0 || password.text.length == 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete All Fields" message:@"You must complete all fields to login!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Good" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }else{
        //if you are using xibs use this line
        UIViewController *anotherUIViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"anotherUIViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        //
        //if you are using storyboards use this line
        UIViewController *anotherUIViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifierForThisController"];
        //
        //then simply present the view controller
        [self presentViewController:anotherUIViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```